# Exception: Argument must be either a FieldInfo or PropertyInfo On server

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, linq-to-sql, windows-server-2008

The Environment:

- Development PC: Windows 7 x64 clean install, visual studio 2012 and
  IIS 7.5
- Deployment Server: Windows 2008 w/ sp2, iis 7, .Net 4.0 (not sure if it's 32 or 64 bit)
- Language: VB
- Codebase: Originally classic ASP, with new code additions done in ASP.NET using

The backstory:

I was rewriting a section of our intranet admin site.  I have a bunch of code (20+ files) under directories in App_Code with 2 namespaces defined.  I also have an aspx page in a subfolder of the site that uses the code in App_Code.  I am running a Linq query that pulls down some data from a SqlServer to display on the page.

The issue:

When the code is deployed to the server, the linq-to-sql query errors out with

```
Stack Trace:
    [ArgumentException: Argument must be either a FieldInfo or PropertyInfo]
    System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateSettableFieldOrPropertyMember(MemberInfo member, Type& memberType) +2751766
    System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Bind(MemberInfo member, Expression expression) +48
    {my aspx file class}.{defined function} in {my aspx.vb file}
    {my aspx file class}.pageLoad() in {my aspx.vb file}
    {my aspx file class}._Lambda$__1(Object a0, EventArgs a1) in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\06df741c\5a279add\App_Web_{my aspx file name}.aspx.2589a445.y_7knnxz.0.vb:0
    System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
    System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207
```

The linq query runs fine on my local machine's IIS server, and in Visual Studio 2012's dev server;  just not on the public web server.

Other linq queries on other .net aspx pages do work, and have used many functions this way.  I have tried removing namespaces, adding the line continuation characters, etc... trying to shotgun hairbrained ideas at it.  I have searched as much as I could to find the answer, and all i can find are code files that throw the error.

I am currently in the proccess of trying to clone the environment in a vm (Run an eval copy of server 2008) and host the site in it.

Any help that could be offered will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears there was an issue with the way the environment on the server was handling public variables vs public properties with the linq queries when i was doing my

```
Select New MyClass With { .var1 = result.variable }
```

I added the property modifier to my variable:

```
Class MyClass
    Public Property var1
End Class
```

instead of

```
Class MyClass
    Public var1
End Class
```